# How to include dagger 2?

Tags: java, android, gradle, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I am trying to use Dagger 2 for dependency injection. Currently I am adding the depenecies like this.

In build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
}
```

In app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'


dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.2'
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.2'
    provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
}
```

The problem is, We are creating a SDK (module), which will be included by other apps so I don't want to include the dependency in build.gradle. Because of this, I will have to tell the other apps to include `Dagger2` dependency in their main build.gradle file.

Also, let me know if there is any way to include dagger library using jar.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Well I am pretty sure you can download the JARs from the maven repository http://mavensearch.io/repo/com.google.dagger/dagger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

add this to your build.gradle

```
dependencies {
 // other classpath definitions here
 classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
}
```

Then in your app/build.gradle:

```
 apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

 dependencies {
    // apt command comes from the android-apt plugin
   apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.2'
   compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.2'
   provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
 }
```

Note that the provided keyword refers to dependencies that are only needed at compilation.

Hope this helps

Comment: Look at the builds your using classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.3' while I am saying use this classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8' it looks a little bit different don't it

Comment: I think your using an old version

Comment: Sorry for that, but yes, I have included the desired dependency and its working. But I don't want to include the dependency in main `build.gradle`.

Comment: I see what you mean now but jars are very hard to do in studio and are not supported any more from what I gathered. But you can try this it works for Volley: you build the jar or download it from maven, then add this to your project     "compile files('libs/daggar2.jar')"      this should do the trick I would think